# java, convert windows path to dos 8.3 format

Tags: java, windows

anyone knows any java utility method that would convert windows paths to DOS 8.3 format ?  thanks

Comment: Are you looking for how to access the windows API or are you looking for matching logic that stays within the java vm?

Comment: either way is ok, without importing any external lib would be the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](http://dolf.trieschnigg.nl/eightpointthree/eightpointthree.html)

Comment: I found this prior of posting, I thought that there might be an easier way

Answer (score 2):

you could also use the GPL-licensed [Servertec Foundation Classes (SFC)](http://www.servertec.com/products/sfc/sfc.html), which have a [stec.sfc.Win32.File::getShortPathName()](http://www.servertec.com/products/sfc/docs/stec/sfc/Win32/File.html#getShortPathName%28%29).

in the end, parsing the output of `dir /X` might be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no "method" for such "conversion". Only you can do is **retrieve** from filesytem 8.3 filename variant (if exists in filesystem).